# Fancy box making image disappear on rails

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, fancybox

Hi my fancy box image keeps disappearing whenever I click on the image,the fancy box displays the image but once I close it theirs no image. Where am I going wrong?

Fancybox javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".single_image").fancybox();
});
```

Fancybox Image:

```
<%= link_to(image_tag"blindlogo.jpg", :class=>"single_image") %>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Updated**

Try to add following codes below your link_to codes, so it looks like:

```
<%= link_to "#", "assets/blindlogo.jpg", :class=>"single_image" %>
```

See http://fancybox.net/howto. This page says you need href in your link element.

Comment: I get two images instead one with a link and it disappears when I click on it and another which stays and has no links.

Comment: Will the updated version work?
`<%= link_to "#", "assets/blindlogo.jpg", :class=>"single_image" %>`

Comment: I have changed it to this <%= link_to "#", "assets/blindlogo.jpg", :class=>"single_image" %> and it shows # and i click on it the image shows. I sorted of understand that for this to work you need one small image and one big one to link to, but I don't know the rails code to do this.What else am I doing wrong?

Comment: From the howto link I provided above, I see following codes will meet your needs: `<a id="single_image" href="image_big.jpg"><img src="image_small.jpg" alt=""/></a>`